# Unix repeat line number for each group in file based on patern probabelly with awk

Tags: unix, awk, ldif

I need help with text file specific record numbering.
This is ldif file and it will be about 2GB. Processing machine is unix so I typed awk. While already tried nl and cat it looks more complicated and awk looks good for this task, I'm familiar with sql but this is not close to it :-)

Goal is to guarantee numerical uniqueness for group and elements of group:

1. Add column with repeating number to each row in data group starting with attribute 'dn:' (it can be repeated row number or counter) important thing is it should be unique among groups.
2. Add column with incremental number when attribute is repeating.

Input:

```
dn: uc=an
version: 12

dn: uid=fcb
uid: ljfhsfff
missdata: at12
missdata: at3
fladata: part2
fladata: part3
fladata: part1

dn: uid=fccb
uid: kjhfa8
missdata: at1
missdata: at8
missdata: at10
missdata: at14
fladata:: a06b6a==
fladata: part3
att: dsc
```

Output(one of possible):

```
1 1 dn: uc=an
1 1 version: 12

2 1 dn: uid=fcb
2 1 uid: ljfhsfff
2 1 missdata: at12
2 2 missdata: at3
2 1 fladata: part2
2 2 fladata: part3
2 3 fladata: part1

3 1 dn: uid=fccb
3 1 uid: kjhfa8
3 1 missdata: at1
3 2 missdata: at8
3 3 missdata: at10
3 4 missdata: at14
3 1 fladata:: a06b6a==
3 2 fladata: part3
3 1 att: dsc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F':' '{if (NF) {$0 = (grpNr+1) OFS (++eltCnt[$1]) OFS $0} else {++grpNr; delete eltCnt}} 1' file
1 1 dn: uc=an
1 1 version: 12

2 1 dn: uid=fcb
2 1 uid: ljfhsfff
2 1 missdata: at12
2 2 missdata: at3
2 1 fladata: part2
2 2 fladata: part3
2 3 fladata: part1

3 1 dn: uid=fccb
3 1 uid: kjhfa8
3 1 missdata: at1
3 2 missdata: at8
3 3 missdata: at10
3 4 missdata: at14
3 1 fladata:: a06b6a==
3 2 fladata: part3
3 1 att: dsc
```

Comment: Saw your replies previously - You are the best. It works as expected in linux however this is solaris so guess should replace delete eltCnt with split("", array, ":") and probably use nawk right ?

Comment: On Solaris you should use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk, not nawk (pre-POSIX) and definitely not /bin/awk (old, broken awk). Yes you MIGHT need to `use split("",eltCnt)` instead of `delete eltCnt` but try the latter first. You wouldn't need the 3rg arg for split() if you did use it.

Comment: Thanks again Ed, I found this version yesterday and has implemented `delete`. Meanwhile I familiarized with awk and realized that I can pivot data from ldif to csv directly. Based on examples i have already working script but unfortunately cant operate on multiple attributes with same name (as above). I will try to figure this out or ask new question with that i'v already done.